# Facebook Android app installs not showing up on app dashboard

Tags: android, facebook

I'm running a pay-per-install campaign on iOS an Android. The iOS installs seem to be tracking on the app dashboard, but no Android installs are being reported (there are installs though).

I'm trying to confirm reporting as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/).

> You can confirm that the volume of installs is being correctly reported in the Insights section for your app in the App Dashboard under "Mobile App Installs". In addition, in the App Summary Page, after choosing your app, there is a time stamp 'Last Mobile Install Reported" for iOS and Android so that you can confirm that an install is being reported (see image below).

I'm calling `AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getActivity(), getString(R.string.fb_app_id));` in my activities as instructed.

I also have the proguard lines to keep the SDK working.

Is there something else I'm missing? Is this a bug on Facebook's end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like misleading info in the documentation. Tracking was working. Real users are showing up on the dashboard, but my own devices were not.